# Android pick intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pick a file with any of these 3 mime types, and it doesn't seem to work

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*, video/*, audio/*");
```

Can someone suggest how I  can do it ?

Comment: Have you tried `photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*")`;

Comment: Yes, But I don't want the apps that handle other files, like text editors and others, just the ones who can handle media

Comment: You want to pick file from the external storage??

Answer (score 1):

Write below code instead of your code, it may help you.

```
private static final int PICTURE = 0;
private static final int VIDEO = 1;
private static final int AUDIO = 2; 


Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
String title = GET_PICTURE;

if (this.mediaType == PICTURE) {
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    title = "GET_PICTURE";  
}else if (this.mediaType == VIDEO) {
    photoPickerIntent.setType("video/*");     
    title = "GET_VIDEO";
}else if (this.mediaType == AUDIO) {
    photoPickerIntent.setType("audio/*");     
    title = "GET_AUDIO";
}
```

And Use below links for reference.

[Pick Intent Example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-android/trunk/framework/src/com/phonegap/CameraLauncher.java)

Comment: I've tried this but i would like to handle only media files not all of them

Comment: so basically i cannot set multiple mimeTypes to one intent ?

Comment: @BilltheLizard my answer is always helping to all and the code is so big so that i was not posted here and i will not change my blog post url in future so deletion of my answer is totally unreliable.